# Removing first three characters from a column

Tags: linux, columns

> **chr**II 71865 72972 YBL081W . + SGD gene . ID=YBL081W;Name=YBL081W;Ontology_term=GO:0003674,GO:0005575,GO:0008150;Note=Non-essential%20protein%20of%20unknown%20function%3B%20null%20mutation%20results%20in%20a%20decrease%20in%20plasma%20membrane%20electron%20transport;dbxref=SGD:S000000177;orf_classification=Uncharacterized

I have a bed file with many gene data in the gff format. I need to remove the first 3 characters from the first column e.g chr from the chrII  in the first column and want just the Roman numbers.

I want to see the output like this

> II 71865 72972 YBL081W . + SGD gene .
>   ID=YBL081W;Name=YBL081W;Ontology_term=GO:0003674,GO:0005575,GO:0008150;Note=Non-essential%20protein%20of%20unknown%20function%3B%20null%20mutation%20results%20in%20a%20decrease%20in%20plasma%20membrane%20electron%20transport;dbxref=SGD:S000000177;orf_classification=Uncharacterized

Comment: sed -i -e s/...// file

Comment: @user121954 If you're wondering about the downvotes on your question: You are expected to show that you've done your due diligence (i.e. searched for a solution) when asking a question. If you don't, you'll usually just get a "What have you tried?" and no answers because people are less willing to put effort into an answer if you appear to have put little effort into the question.

Answer (score 0):

This command prints out chars 4 to 500 of every line of `file.gff`, hence cutting out the first 3 chars, and saves the results in `newfile.gff`:

```
cut -c4-500 file.gff > newfile.gff
```

Increase the upper bound accordingly if your lines are longer than 500 chars.